# Startup error Part::partw

Tags: warning-messages, paclets

When I started mathematica, this message popped up.

```
Part::partw: Part 5 of PacletManager`Utils`Private`$taskData[2] does not exist.
```

Does anyone know what this is? My version is mma 11.2.

Comment: Have you ever explicitly interacted with the paclet manager, in any manner?

Comment: No but I installed some packages I don't know if they did. But things were fine when I was using mma 11.1.

Comment: What packages did you install, and how exactly did you do it?

Comment: I installed FeynCalc, FormLink, CollierLink, X, FeynHelper, FIRE, LoopTools, Litered, CARONICA, and mostly I just put them in the Applications folder but some of them requires more and I just follow the instruction and use the auto-install script. Beyond that I did nothing related to paclet manager.

Comment: I see the same warning message on the save version.  Started a few days ago.   The only "special" actions that I have taken are Needs["AuthorTools`"]
NotebookRestore[]

Comment: Same for me on Mathematica 11.3, but not on 11.2........

Comment: I am also getting this in my laptop with Mathematica 11.3 under Windows 7. But not on the desktop. The Laptop is setup with a Network license and the desktop is using a fixed activation key. Could this be the difference? Who knows..

Answer (score 2):

We believe this should be fixed in *Mathematica* 12.0. We were never able to reproduce this internally so we're not completely sure about this, though. Please let us know if this continues to happen in 12.0 for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you encounter this message at the MMA's startup, please check init.m located in %AppData%\Mathematica\FrontEnd. I solved the same problem (I use MMA 11.3) just by deleting entire text/commands in the %AppData%\Mathematica\FrontEnd\init.m file. This init.m is automatically initialized at every system startup and automatically updated by the MMA. Backup the file before deleting any text/commands in this initialization file.